# pfSense (FreeBSD) - tail -f not showing entire log when filtering with cut or sed

Tags: ubuntu, sed, cut, tail, pfsense

I have a strange problem when trying to display logs on pfSense (and I can reproduce the same problem on Ubuntu server also).

The problem is this (with examples):

I'm trying to display a running `dhcp` log with `tail -f`. This works without problem when I just use it, like this:

```
$ tail -n 48 -f /var/log/dhcpd.log 

Feb  4 10:43:01 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05817400] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], cid=[01:dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], tid=0x2cbc27bf: lease 10.10.1.62 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 10:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_START starting Lease File Cleanup
Feb  4 10:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_EXECUTE executing Lease File Cleanup using: /usr/local/sbin/kea-lfc -4 -x /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.2 -i /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.1 -o /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.output -f /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.completed -p /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.pid -c ignored-path
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPREQUEST on igc2 to 147.78.28.48 port 67
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPACK from 147.78.28.48 
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[31021]: RENEW
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[31336]: Creating resolv.conf
Feb  4 10:59:04 vault dhclient[37405]: bound to XX.XX.XX.XX -- renewal in 1800 seconds.
Feb  4 11:00:53 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d058d0000] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_lan_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 11:00:53 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d058d0000] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt4_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 11:00:53 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d058d0000] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt5_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 11:00:53 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d058d0000] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 dc:a6:32:9a:15:72], cid=[ff:92:39:3b:55:00:02:00:00:ab:11:ac:47:9e:3e:13:09:39:5f], tid=0x656556fb: lease 10.10.2.4 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 11:03:43 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d058d0000] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_lan_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 11:03:43 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d058d0000] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt4_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 11:03:43 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d058d0000] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt5_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 11:03:43 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d058d0000] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 04:d4:c4:76:16:b5], cid=[01:04:d4:c4:76:16:b5], tid=0x18d711b8: lease 10.10.2.22 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 11:06:14 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d058d0000] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_lan_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 11:06:14 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d058d0000] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt4_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 11:06:14 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d058d0000] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt5_0 evaluated to 1 
Feb  4 11:06:14 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d058d0000] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 3c:ec:ef:06:a1:c1], cid=[01:3c:ec:ef:06:a1:c1], tid=0x26a022f: lease 10.10.2.1 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPREQUEST on igc2 to 147.78.28.48 port 67 
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPACK from 147.78.28.48  
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[18732]: RENEW
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[19731]: Creating resolv.conf  
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[37405]: bound to XX.XX.XX.XX -- renewal in 1800 seconds.
Feb  4 11:43:01 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05818900] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_lan_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 11:43:01 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05818900] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt4_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 11:43:01 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05818900] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt5_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 11:43:01 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05818900] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], cid=[01:dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], tid=0xac0108b7: lease 10.10.1.62 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 11:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_START starting Lease File Cleanup
Feb  4 11:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_EXECUTE executing Lease File Cleanup using: /usr/local/sbin/kea-lfc -4 -x /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.2 -i /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.1 -o /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.output -f /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.completed -p /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.pid -c ignored-path
Feb  4 11:59:04 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPREQUEST on igc2 to 147.78.28.48 port 67 
Feb  4 11:59:04 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPACK from 147.78.28.48   
Feb  4 11:59:04 vault dhclient[71625]: RENEW  
Feb  4 11:59:04 vault dhclient[72471]: Creating resolv.conf
Feb  4 11:59:04 vault dhclient[37405]: bound to XX.XX.XX.XX -- renewal in 1800 seconds.
Feb  4 12:00:53 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05817400] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_lan_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 12:00:53 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05817400] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt4_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 12:00:53 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05817400] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt5_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 12:00:53 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05817400] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 dc:a6:32:9a:15:72], cid=[ff:92:39:3b:55:00:02:00:00:ab:11:ac:47:9e:3e:13:09:39:5f], tid=0x656556fb: lease 10.10.2.4 has been allocated for 7200 seconds 
Feb  4 12:03:44 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05817400] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_lan_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 12:03:44 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05817400] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt4_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 12:03:44 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05817400] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt5_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 12:03:44 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05817400] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 04:d4:c4:76:16:b5], cid=[01:04:d4:c4:76:16:b5], tid=0x6ba6e88e: lease 10.10.2.22 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 12:06:14 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05817400] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_lan_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 12:06:14 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05817400] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt4_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 12:06:14 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05817400] EVAL_RESULT Expression pool_opt5_0 evaluated to 1
Feb  4 12:06:14 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05817400] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 3c:ec:ef:06:a1:c1], cid=[01:3c:ec:ef:06:a1:c1], tid=0x26a022f: lease 10.10.2.1 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
```

I'll then filter the results with `grep`, which still works as expected:

```
$ tail -n 48 -f /var/log/dhcpd.log | grep -v 'Expression pool'

Feb  4 10:43:01 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05817400] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], cid=[01:dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], tid=0x2cbc27bf: lease 10.10.1.62 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 10:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_START starting Lease File Cleanup
Feb  4 10:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_EXECUTE executing Lease File Cleanup using: /usr/local/sbin/kea-lfc -4 -x /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.2 -i /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.1 -o /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.output -f /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.completed -p /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.pid -c ignored-path
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPREQUEST on igc2 to 147.78.28.48 port 67
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPACK from 147.78.28.48
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[31021]: RENEW
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[31336]: Creating resolv.conf
Feb  4 10:59:04 vault dhclient[37405]: bound to XX.XX.XX.XX -- renewal in 1800 seconds.
Feb  4 11:00:53 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d058d0000] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 dc:a6:32:9a:15:72], cid=[ff:92:39:3b:55:00:02:00:00:ab:11:ac:47:9e:3e:13:09:39:5f], tid=0x656556fb: lease 10.10.2.4 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 11:03:43 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d058d0000] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 04:d4:c4:76:16:b5], cid=[01:04:d4:c4:76:16:b5], tid=0x18d711b8: lease 10.10.2.22 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 11:06:14 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d058d0000] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 3c:ec:ef:06:a1:c1], cid=[01:3c:ec:ef:06:a1:c1], tid=0x26a022f: lease 10.10.2.1 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPREQUEST on igc2 to 147.78.28.48 port 67
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPACK from 147.78.28.48
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[18732]: RENEW
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[19731]: Creating resolv.conf
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[37405]: bound to XX.XX.XX.XX -- renewal in 1800 seconds.
Feb  4 11:43:01 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05818900] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], cid=[01:dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], tid=0xac0108b7: lease 10.10.1.62 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 11:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_START starting Lease File Cleanup
Feb  4 11:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_EXECUTE executing Lease File Cleanup using: /usr/local/sbin/kea-lfc -4 -x /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.2 -i /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.1 -o /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.output -f /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.completed -p /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.pid -c ignored-path
Feb  4 11:59:04 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPREQUEST on igc2 to 147.78.28.48 port 67
Feb  4 11:59:04 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPACK from 147.78.28.48
Feb  4 11:59:04 vault dhclient[71625]: RENEW
Feb  4 11:59:04 vault dhclient[72471]: Creating resolv.conf
Feb  4 11:59:04 vault dhclient[37405]: bound to XX.XX.XX.XX -- renewal in 1800 seconds.
Feb  4 12:00:53 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05817400] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 dc:a6:32:9a:15:72], cid=[ff:92:39:3b:55:00:02:00:00:ab:11:ac:47:9e:3e:13:09:39:5f], tid=0x656556fb: lease 10.10.2.4 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 12:03:44 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05817400] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 04:d4:c4:76:16:b5], cid=[01:04:d4:c4:76:16:b5], tid=0x6ba6e88e: lease 10.10.2.22 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 12:06:14 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05817400] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 3c:ec:ef:06:a1:c1], cid=[01:3c:ec:ef:06:a1:c1], tid=0x26a022f: lease 10.10.2.1 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
```

Finally, I want to cut the column width with `cut` (or make string manipulation with `sed`), but then the problems begin. As you can see from the output, this results in the latest line of the log not being included.

```
$ tail -n 48 -f /var/log/dhcpd.log | grep -v 'Expression pool' | cut -c -223

Feb  4 10:43:01 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05817400] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], cid=[01:dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], tid=0x2cbc27bf: lease 10.10.1.62 has been allocated for 7200 second
Feb  4 10:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_START starting Lease File Cleanup
Feb  4 10:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_EXECUTE executing Lease File Cleanup using: /usr/local/sbin/kea-lfc -4 -x /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.2 -i /var/lib/kea/dhcp
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPREQUEST on igc2 to 147.78.28.48 port 67
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPACK from 147.78.28.48
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[31021]: RENEW
Feb  4 10:59:03 vault dhclient[31336]: Creating resolv.conf
Feb  4 10:59:04 vault dhclient[37405]: bound to XX.XX.XX.XX -- renewal in 1800 seconds.
Feb  4 11:00:53 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d058d0000] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 dc:a6:32:9a:15:72], cid=[ff:92:39:3b:55:00:02:00:00:ab:11:ac:47:9e:3e:13:09:39:5f], tid=0x656556fb: lease 10.10.2.4
Feb  4 11:03:43 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d058d0000] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 04:d4:c4:76:16:b5], cid=[01:04:d4:c4:76:16:b5], tid=0x18d711b8: lease 10.10.2.22 has been allocated for 7200 second
Feb  4 11:06:14 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d058d0000] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 3c:ec:ef:06:a1:c1], cid=[01:3c:ec:ef:06:a1:c1], tid=0x26a022f: lease 10.10.2.1 has been allocated for 7200 seconds
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPREQUEST on igc2 to 147.78.28.48 port 67
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[37405]: DHCPACK from 147.78.28.48
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[18732]: RENEW
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[19731]: Creating resolv.conf
Feb  4 11:29:04 vault dhclient[37405]: bound to XX.XX.XX.XX -- renewal in 1800 seconds.
Feb  4 11:43:01 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases.0x313d05818900] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], cid=[01:dc:e5:5b:91:28:97], tid=0xac0108b7: lease 10.10.1.62 has been allocated for 7200 second
Feb  4 11:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_START starting Lease File Cleanup
Feb  4 11:51:54 vault kea-dhcp4[96084]: INFO  [kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv.0x313d05812000] DHCPSRV_MEMFILE_LFC_EXECUTE executing Lease File Cleanup using: /usr/local/sbin/kea-lfc -4 -x /var/lib/kea/dhcp4.leases.2 -i /var/lib/kea/dhcp
```

As you can see, the timestamps with cut stop with `11:51:54`, while the latest entry is in fact `12:06:14`. This is completely reproducible, but it differs how much of the log tail is not included.

Also, this is both tested on pfSense and Ubuntu, with `cut` and `sed`, and I get the same behavior of the entire log tail not getting included most of the time.

Can anyone explain what's happening here? And any suggestions for a working method to do this? I would like to follow the log tail, while at the same time being able to filter the output with `cut` and/or `sed`, and be sure that the latest lines are always included.

Comment: You may need the `--line-buffered` switch with the `grep` command.

Comment: Thank you, `--line-buffered` works as expected.